# How to give Workflows service agent access to a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-workflows

I am following Google Cloud Workflows guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/workflows/quickstart-storage)

At the [third step where you create and deploy the workflow](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/workflows/quickstart-storage#create_and_deploy_a_workflow)...

I tried the following command:

```
export MY_WORKFLOW=myEventWorkflow
gcloud workflows deploy ${MY_WORKFLOW} --source=myEventWorkflow.yaml
```

and I received the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.workflows.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Workflows service agent doesn't have permission to access the service account to be used as workflow identity. Please check your IAM settings.
```

How can I solve this error? I am not quite sure what a workflow service agent is.

Comment: This [document](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/authentication) shows how to set up Workflows authorization. Near the bottom is how to look up the service account information. The service Agent format is `service-WORKFLOWS_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-workflows.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: You need to grant the service account token creator role on the service agent service account (format provided by @JohnHanley). You can grant access only on the target service account, or project wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Hanley and Guillaume Blaquiere mentioned

As per this official  [doc](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/authentication#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Service%20account%20list,to%20the%20Workflows%20service%20agent.)

> **To give Workflows service agents access to a service account follow the below process**:
>
> - In the Google Cloud console, go to the Workflows page:   [Go to Workflows](https://console.cloud.google.com/workflows)
> - Click add Create to create a workflow or select the name of the workflow that you want to update.
> - In the Service account list, click the Switch project.
> - Select a service account from a different project.
> - If prompted, grant the roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator role to the Workflows service agent.
>
> You  need to Grant the Service Account Token Creator role
> (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) to the Workflows service agent.
> This permits the service agent to manage the cross-project access for
> the service account. A service agent is the identity of a given Google
> Cloud service for a particular project. For more information, see
> [Service agents](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents).